# Extract values from nested dict for function call

Tags: python

I have a dict as below, now this dict can grow in depth and length.

```
d = {"menu": {"Mozilla Firefox": {}}, "toolbar": {}, "tags": {}, "unfiled": {"694": {"title": "Drinking water 'forever chemical' level set too high, say scientists - BBC News", "url": "https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-60761972", "date": 1647679593.094, "modified": 1647679602.993}, "697": {"title": "What will climate change look like in your area? - BBC News", "url": "https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/resources/idt-d6338d9f-8789-4bc2-b6d7-3691c0e7d138", "date": 1647679649.588, "modified": 1647679649.588}, "1026": {"title": "Gareth Bale: Wales and Real Madrid forward hits back at Spanish media - BBC Sport", "url": "https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/60876341", "date": 1648292175.24, "modified": 1648292175.24}}, "mobile": {}}
```

I need to loop through this dict and pass each related title, url into another function no matter what the parent.   I need to ignore any other parents/children

Here's the code I have to loop through this nested dict - this gives me all the data through printing - half way there I feel.

```
def traverse(value, key=None):
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        for k, v in value.items():
            yield from traverse(v, k)
    else:
        yield key, value

def myprint(d):
    for k, v in traverse(d):
        print(f"{k} : {v}")
```

I was thinking of dumping the title/url into a list.  I suppose I can do that in myprint() by appending with a condition on k.  I could then call the function by iterating over a simple list.

Is that the best way to do this?  or is there a more pythonic way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tbh, I think your approach is fine, but just if I were you I will return the whole dictionary. Since usually you want to do manipulate more than just the `title` & `url`.

```py
mydict = {"menu": {"Mozilla Firefox": {}}, "toolbar": {}, "tags": {}, "unfiled": {"694": {"title": "Drinking water 'forever chemical' level set too high, say scientists - BBC News", "url": "https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-60761972", "date": 1647679593.094, "modified": 1647679602.993}, "697": {"title": "What will climate change look like in your area? - BBC News", "url": "https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/resources/idt-d6338d9f-8789-4bc2-b6d7-3691c0e7d138", "date": 1647679649.588, "modified": 1647679649.588}, "1026": {"title": "Gareth Bale: Wales and Real Madrid forward hits back at Spanish media - BBC Sport", "url": "https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/60876341", "date": 1648292175.24, "modified": 1648292175.24}}, "mobile": {}}

def traverse(value: Dict[str, str]):
    if "title" in value and "url" in value:
        yield value
    elif isinstance(value, dict):
        for v in value.values():
            yield from traverse(v)

def myprint(d):
    for v in traverse(d):
        print(v)

your_list = list(traverse(mydict))
myprint(mydict)
# {'title': "Drinking water 'forever chemical' level set too high, say scientists - BBC News", 'url': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-60761972', 'date': 1647679593.094, 'modified': 1647679602.993}    
# {'title': 'What will climate change look like in your area? - BBC News', 'url': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/resources/idt-d6338d9f-8789-4bc2-b6d7-3691c0e7d138', 'date': 1647679649.588, 'modified': 1647679649.588}  
# {'title': 'Gareth Bale: Wales and Real Madrid forward hits back at Spanish media - BBC Sport', 'url': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/60876341', 'date': 1648292175.24, 'modified': 1648292175.24}
```